# Yii2 xml XmlResponseFormatter

Tags: xml, yii2, xml-formatting

I am trying to build a XML response with Yii2. But i've some problems with  [itemtag](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-xmlresponseformatter.html#$itemTag-detail)

Itemtag names the elements in the array that represents the numeric keys. **Example**

```
$itemTag = 'test';

return $response = ['tests' => [0 => 'a', 1 => 'b']];
```

**XML RESULT**

```
<response>
   <tests>
      <test>a</test>
      <test>b</test>
   </tests>
</response>
```

But when i want to create within test a new group its still getting itemtag name. **Example**

```
return $response = ['tests' => [0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 'days' => [0 => 'd1', 1 => 'd2']]];
```

ANd this is the xml result

```
<response>
  <tests>
    <test>a</test>
    <test>b</test>
    <days>
      <test>d1</test> // this should be day
      <test>d2</test> // this should be day
    </days>
  </tests>
</response>
```

How could i solve this issue?

Comment: I'm assuming that this code is in your controller? Can you show the code for the whole action, in your controller? It's hard to see what is going on without it

Answer (score 0):

Let make your custom XmlResponseFormatter and override this function:

```
protected function buildXml($element, $data)
{
    if (is_array($data)
        || ($data instanceof \Traversable
        && $this->useTraversableAsArray
        && !$data instanceof Arrayable)
    ) {

        foreach ($data as $name => $value) {

            if(is_array($value) && $this->checkArrayKeyNumber($value)){
                foreach ($value as $number => $childValue) {
                    $ele = new DOMElement($name);
                    $element->insertBefore(
                        $element->ownerDocument->createTextNode("\n")
                    );
                    $element->appendChild($ele);
                    $this->buildXml($ele, $childValue);
                }
                continue;
            }

            if (is_int($name) && is_object($value)) {
                $this->buildXml($element, $value);
            } elseif (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
                $child = new DOMElement($this->getValidXmlElementName($name));
                $element->insertBefore(
                    $element->ownerDocument->createTextNode("\n")
                );
                $element->appendChild($child);
                $this->buildXml($child, $value);
            } else {
                $child = new DOMElement($this->getValidXmlElementName($name));
                $element->insertBefore(
                    $element->ownerDocument->createTextNode("\n")
                );
                $element->appendChild($child);
                $child->appendChild(
                    new DOMText($this->formatScalarValue($value))
                );
            }
        }

    } elseif (is_object($data)) {
        if ($this->useObjectTags) {
            $child = new DOMElement(StringHelper::basename(get_class($data)));
            $element->appendChild($child);
        } else {
            $child = $element;
        }
        if ($data instanceof Arrayable) {
            $this->buildXml($child, $data->toArray());
        } else {
            $array = [];
            foreach ($data as $name => $value) {
                $array[$name] = $value;
            }
            $this->buildXml($child, $array);
        }
    } else {
        $element->appendChild(new DOMText($this->formatScalarValue($data)));
    }
    $element->insertBefore(
        $element->ownerDocument->createTextNode("\n")
    );
}
```

Add new function to check where your array data has key is numeric, for example

```
[
    'days' =>
    [
        0  => 'd1',
        1  => 'd2'
    ]
]
```

this function

```
private function checkArrayKeyNumber($array)
{
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    $numeric = true;
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if(!is_numeric($key)){
            $numeric = false;
        }
    }

    return $numeric;
}
```

Finally, add to your custom response class init()

```
    public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    $this->formatters['xml']
        = 'path\to\your\custom\XmlResponseFormatter';
}
```